# What is the meaning of "Or else"

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning, definition

Okay. Okay. I am just going to get up, go to work and not think about him all day. Or else I'm just gonna get up and go to work.

Comment: Is it same as "otherwise"

Comment: [Or else](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/or%20else) has a dictionary entry …

Comment: Source of the quote please.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does mean "otherwise."

Someone is saying that she plans to get up, go to work, and not think about him all day. But if she fails to do exactly that (because she does think about him all day) then she will keep at least certain parts of the plan: she will still get up and go to work.

"Or else" is a very common expression, used here in the usual way.

Comment: Thnx this was helpful